# reading a .txt file, C

Tags: c, parsing

I am trying to parse through a line a line of text from a .txt file and set it to a string. It is parsing most of the lines, except for the first 4 characters. This is what I'm trying to parse:

> 12X6 de8 dw3 ds5 g8,7 m3,4 p2,2 h2,2

And this is my code:

```
FILE * rooms;
int i;
char c;
char roomString[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];    
rooms = fopen("assets/rooms.txt", "r");

if(rooms == NULL)
{
    printf("error opening file\n");
}

fscanf(rooms, "%s", roomString);
while((c=fgetc(rooms))!='\n')
{           
    roomString[i] = c;
    i++;
}
printf("%s\n", roomString);
```

Comment: `c` should be an `int` not a `char`. You also need to init `i`, e.g. `i = 0;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fscanf()` call consumes the first word of the input. Remove that call.

```
if(rooms == NULL)
{
    printf("error opening file\n");
}

//fscanf(rooms, "%s", roomString);
while((c=fgetc(rooms))!='\n')
```

Comment: Beat me to it as I was about to hit submit.

Comment: Thank you, another question, how would i go about scanning multiple lines of text in same format as the one above?

Comment: You could enclose your code in a loop, or rewrite to use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) which reads full lines on its own.

Comment: If i enclose it in a loop will fgetc skip to the next line if i switch the "while((c=fgetc(rooms))!='\n')" to "while((c=fgetc(rooms))!=EOF)

Comment: No. Your outer loop tests for `EOF`; your inner loop tests for `'\n'` as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you do fscanf when you are doing fgetc. This fscanf increments the file pointer to the next word. Remove the fscanf and execute your code with the mentioned changes.

```
   #include<stdio.h>

   #define ROOM_STRING_LENGTH 50
    void main(){

    FILE* rooms;
    int i =0;
     char c;
     char roomString[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];    
     rooms = fopen("rooms.txt", "r");
     if(rooms == NULL)
     {
        printf("error opening file\n");
      }

     //fscanf(rooms, "%s", roomString);
      //printf("%s\n", roomString);
     while((c=fgetc(rooms))!='\n')
     {

        roomString[i] = c;
         i++;
     }
     roomString[i] ='\0';
     printf("%s\n", roomString);
  }
```